# Регулярные выражения regexp

Tags: python

с помощью re.search мне нужно вытащить из addresses все номера дома и квартир, и названия улиц и городов, я уже пол дня не понимаю как это сделать, смог вытащить только названия городов (и то не правильно) ИЛИ номера
пример кода

```
import re

addresses = [
    ('Он проживал в городе Иваново на улице Наумова. '
     'Номер дома 125 был зеркальной копией его номера квартиры 521'),
    'Адрес: город Новосибирск, улица Фрунзе, дом 321, квартира 15.'
]

for address in addresses:
    # pattern = r'/d+'
    pattern = r'(Н.?[ув](\w+))'
    address_match = re.search(pattern, address)
    print(address_match)
```

Comment: Это очень непростая задача, одними регулярками она не решается. Возьмите готовую библиотеку, например, https://github.com/natasha/natasha там есть `AddrExtractor` для этой задачи.

Answer (score 0):

в итоге, решение такое:

```
import re

addresses = [
    ('Он проживал в городе Иваново на улице Наумова. '
     'Номер дома 125 был зеркальной копией его номера квартиры 521'),
    'Адрес: город Новосибирск, улица Фрунзе, дом 321, квартира 15.'
]

result = []

for address in addresses:
    pattern = f'город.? (?P<town>\w+).*улиц.? (?P<street>\w+).*дом.? (?P<house>\d+).*квартир.? (?P<apartment>\d+)'
    address_match = re.search(pattern, address)

    result.append(address_match.groups())

for row in result:
    print(*row)
```